# error: variable-sized object may not be initialized. i don't understand why?

Tags: c, image, blur

This algorithm is meant to blur an image by calculating the average of color degree in the pixels before and after and above and below the targeted pixel (including the pixel itself) forming a 3×3 box.
but I keep getting this error can someone explaing me why?

```
for (int i = 1; i < width - 1; i++)
{
    //error comes from this line 
    float blur_Red_leftedge[i - 1] = image[0][i].rgbtRed + image[1][i].rgbtRed + image[0][i - 1].rgbtRed + image[1][i - 1].rgbtRed + image[0][i + 1].rgbtRed + image[1][i + 1].rgbtRed;
    float blurRed_leftedge[i - 1] = (blur_Red_leftedge[i - 1] / 6);
    blurRed_leftedge[i - 1] = round(blurRed_leftedge[i - 1]);
    
    //and this line
    float blur_Green_leftedge[i] = image[0][i].rgbtGreen + image[1][i].rgbtGreen + image[0][i - 1].rgbtGreen + image[1][i - 1].rgbtGreen + image[0][i + 1].rgbtGreen + image[1][i + 1].rgbtGreen;
    float blurGreen_leftedge[i] = (blur_Green_leftedge[i] / 6);
    blurGreen_leftedge[i] = round(blurGreen_leftedge[i]);
    
    //and this
    float blur_Blue_leftedge[i] = image[0][i].rgbtBlue + image[1][i].rgbtBlue + image[0][i - 1].rgbtBlue + image[1][i - 1].rgbtBlue + image[0][i + 1].rgbtBlue + image[1][i + 1].rgbtBlue;
    float blurBlue_leftedge[i] = (blur_Blue_leftedge[i] / 6);
    blurBlue_leftedge[i] = round(blurBlue_leftedge[i]);
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to declare two `float` arrays with names `blur_Red_leftedge` and `blurRed_leftedge`?

Comment: Delete "float".

Comment: why? and which one?

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from the following declarations:

```
float blur_Red_leftedge[i - 1] = ...;
```

This is a definition of Variable Length Array (VLA) of `i - 1` floats.
The rest of the line (`...` part) is treated as an initializer.
And the C standard explicitly disallows VLAs have initializer.

The code is not full thus it is difficult to say how it should be fixed.
I guess that dropping `float` and making declarations an assignment expressions may be a good start.

Comment: I added the (i - 1) because i thought it is the problem if you can see the loop starts from 1 so blur_Red_leftedge[0] is left blank.

Comment: I think you're confusing C arrays with dict/maps of other languages. A C array has a static size when declared, accessed with an index 0 to size-1. In something like Python, `blur_Red_leftedge[i - 1]` creates a new entry within `blur_Red_leftedge`, but in C adding the `float` type means create an array of that size (and the right side doesn't make sense in that case - you can assign an array with e.g. `{ 1.0, 1.1. 2.0 }`, but not a single value). Declare your arrays outside the `for` loop, then access them normally (don't include `float` or you'll declare a new array of the same name).

Comment: so im creating a new array called <blur_Red_leftedge> every time the loop runs a new circle?